# Problems with executing Input task twice in Ant

Tags: ant

I have some problems with `<input>` task in Ant. 
When I'm trying to execute:

`<input id="2" message="Please enter password" addproperty="password"/>
 <input id="1" message="Please enter username" addproperty="user">`

I getting this error after first input is executed:
***Failed to read input from Console***

It seems like I can't execute `<input>` task twice. Can anyone help me with this? I want to get username and password through console.

Comment: I just copy/pasted your exact code, and aside from a syntax error (no closing `/` at the end of the second input task), everything worked as expected. Are you executing this script from another program, or just running it from the command line?

Comment: I'm executing ant script through maven (using maven antrun plugin) from command line

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like this is an old bug that never received much attention (https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=42544). Your script should still work outside of Maven, though.

Comment: Thank you for helping me :) . I changed the version of maven-antrun plugin to version 1.8 (before was 1.7) and now it works fine :) :)